# Solving the system $x^4=y+z$, $y^4=x+z$, $z^4=x+y$ with high school math

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$$\begin{align}
x^4=y+z\\[4pt]
y^4=x+z\\[4pt]
z^4=x+y
\end{align}$$
I need to solve this system of equations for all possible real triplets $(x,y,z)$ but with high school math (it's from an university's admission test's past papers).

Every path I try to follow seems to be a dead end. Any help, suggestion or tip would be appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: You should show at least one of your dead ends.  Meanwhile, subtract the first two equations and factor as much as possible

Comment: Are $x,y,z$ assumed to be *real* or are they allowed to be complex numbers?

Comment: And more seriously....are you sure that going online to get help on your math question is allowed.

Comment: @Mike  When I used to give placement tests, I allowed all the cheating anyone wanted to do.  Their reward is being placed in a math class far too hard for them.  Even worse if you cheat your way into a university that's far too hard for you.

Comment: I'm personally not a fan of getting help for these types of questions. Anyway I downvoted the question and voted to close for that reason--even though the math question itself is interesting.

Comment: @B.Goddard Yeah I should have sorry, anyway I would have shown the same thing that Pedro Ignacio did (now that i know it may lead to something i'm going to try again, thanks Pedro)

Comment: @Mike do not worry mike, It's one of the past papers of the test, i'm just practicing for the test, i'm asking for help since there is no solutions paper

Comment: @CutesyEagle8015 moving forward it is better for anyone asking to be very clear to be where the question came from, and the work already done. Even besides that though, as written, it still needs further details that should have been included at the first writing. Are $x,y,z$ restricted to the real numbers or are they allowed to be complex non-real?

Comment: @Mike sorry Mike, as you can see I'm relatively new to this forum so I still may not be as clear as needed. The solutions are real only

Comment: @CutesyEagle8015 that is fair. We do tend to be leery of answering homework/test questions on here. Anyways I revised my vote. welcome!

Comment: Oof, according to Macaulay2 if you allowed for complex solutions, the equation it gives for $z$ after eliminating $x$ and $y$ would be a degree 40 polynomial with 8 terms.  (Not sure whether that polynomial is square-free or not; if not, there might be a simpler expression.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Assuming $x,y,z$ are restricted to the reals as per the comments:**

Subtracting one of the equations from the other yields
$$x^4-y^4 = y-x.$$ Factoring gives $$(x-y)(x+y)(x^2+y^2) = (y-x),$$ or equivalently, $$(x-y)z^4(x^2+y^2) = (y-x).$$

Now we use the condition that $x,y,z$ must be real. If $x \not = y$ then cancelling gives $z^4(x^2+y^2)=-1,$ which is impossible for real $x,y,z$. So the equation $x=y$ must hold. Likewise, one can use the same line of reasoning to conclude $$y=z$$ and $$z=x.$$

Thus, the conditions reduce to $$x^4=2x,$$ and $$x=y=z.$$ This gives $x \in \{0,\sqrt[3]{2} \}$, and $y=z=x$.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike! I was very close to the answer, but didn't think about the negative sign. Thank you very much for your time, next time I'll try to be more clear :)

Comment: All good glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

What if you make them zero $(0,0,0)$?
$$0^4=0+0$$
$$0^4=0+0$$
$$0^4=0+0$$
If you look for real solutions you also have $(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2})$:
$$(\sqrt[3]{2})^4=\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{2}$$
$$(\sqrt[3]{2})^4=\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{2}$$
$$(\sqrt[3]{2})^4=\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{2}$$

Comment: If people are downvoting this answer, it would be helpful to state why. @Sigrid, how do you know that these are the only solutions.

Comment: I'm a little newbie, I'll try to answer better the next time in order to improve, thanks for your feedback. I really appreciate it.